# 404 not found in !define AWS icons for PlantUML diagram

Tags: plantuml

I have a diagram with AWS icons included, however the link used in !define is not reachable.  How can I define it properly so that I can use the following that need to be included in my diagram?

```
!define AWSPuml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/awslabs/aws-icons-for-plantuml/v15.0/dist
!include AWSPuml/AWSCommon.puml
!include AWSPuml/AWSSimplified.puml
!include AWSPuml/FrontEndWebMobile/FrontEndWebMobile.puml
!include AWSPuml/General/Mobileclient.puml
!include AWSPuml/InternetOfThings/IoTGreengrassProtocol.puml
!include AWSPuml/ApplicationIntegration/ConsoleMobileApplication.puml
```

I have tried several approaches but the examples I found were not clear enough.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77643490/1168342