# VScode (Code-OSS) can't display plantUML - can't find sprite library awslib

Tags: linux, markdown, archlinux, plantuml

I am in Archlinux and I have installed plantuml and VSCode. In VSCode I try to use the following Markdown code:

```
@startuml
!include <awslib/AWSCommon>
!include <awslib/AWSSimplified.puml>
!include <awslib/Compute/all.puml>
!include <awslib/mobile/all.puml>
!include <awslib/general/all.puml>
!include <awslib/GroupIcons/all.puml>


 skinparam linetype polyline
' skinparam linetype ortho


package "AWS Cloud" {
EC2(Smadex, "Smadex Service", " ")
}


Users(Users, "Users", " ")
TraditionalServer(AdExchange, "Ad Exchange", " ")
Mobile(Mobile, "Publisher app or web", " ")


Users -down-> Mobile: 1. Visits
Mobile -right-> AdExchange: 2. Start auction
AdExchange -right-> Smadex: 3. Bid request / response
Smadex -left-> Mobile: 4. Show Ad
Users -right-> Smadex: 5. Impression / click / install / event {request id}
@enduml
```

However, I get the following error:

```
!include <awslib/mobile/all.puml>
cannot include <awslib/mobile/all.puml>
```

I think because plantuml can't find plantuml sprite library . Any suggestions ?

I try to avoid importing the `https://raw.github...` direct URL link and using a different `import` statement as `import AWSLib/...`

I was expecting to see the plantuml diagram in Markdown Preview. I am expecting to be able to download the `.puml` file and import the AWS library on the `plantuml` path (`classpath`) and the `plantuml.jar` (`/usr/share/java/plantuml/plantuml.jar`) used in VSCode (OSS-Code) to be able automatically use/be able to import `awslib`.

Note: This question is not specific for `archlinux` and can be applied to linux in general and not only to `awslib` sprite library, but could be applied to any `plantuml` sprite library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macros evolved to not have Pascal case. And a few macros moved. Here's a working solution on plantuml.com:

```
@startuml
!include <awslib/AWSCommon>
!include <aws/common>
!include <awslib/AWSSimplified.puml>
!include <awslib/Compute/all.puml>
!include <awslib/General/all.puml>
!include <awslib/GroupIcons/all.puml>


 skinparam linetype polyline
' skinparam linetype ortho


package "AWS Cloud" {
EC2(Smadex, "Smadex Service", " ")
}


Users(Users, "Users", " ")

Traditionalserver(AdExchange, "Ad Exchange", " ")

Mobileclient(Mobile, "Publisher app or web", " ")


Users -down-> Mobile: 1. Visits
Mobile -right-> AdExchange: 2. Start auction
AdExchange -right-> Smadex: 3. Bid request / response
Smadex -left-> Mobile: 4. Show Ad
Users -right-> Smadex: 5. Impression / click / install / event {request id}
@enduml
```

[image: plantuml image]